# How to find the upper and lower bounds of $\lim_{p \to \infty}f(p)/p$?

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds

> $p$ is a prime number,$A_{p-1}$ is an array with a length of $p-1$, and the i-th item is $(i!\mod p)\ $($1≤i≤p-1$).$f(p)\ $is the number of different elements present in array $A$.Try to find the upper and lower bounds of $\lim_{p \to \infty}f(p)/p$.

I meet this question in Shuzhimi(a chinese BBS),someone discuss for it.They guess $f(p)/p\sim(1-e^{-1})\  \  \ as\ \ \ {p \to \infty}$.But proving it seems difficult.I calculate the situations when $p≤19$.

$$p=2,f(p)=1$$
$$p=3,f(p)=2$$
$$p=5,f(p)=3$$
$$p=7,f(p)=4$$
$$p=11,f(p)=5$$
$$p=13,f(p)=9$$
$$p=17,f(p)=11$$
$$p=19,f(p)=11$$

Comment: $\lim_{p\to\infty} f(p)\sim g(p)$ is nonsensical notation. We just write $f(p)\sim g(p)$ as $p\to\infty.$

Comment: In any event, since $f(p)\geq 1$ it is not possible that $(1-e^{-1})/p$ is asymptotic. Maybe it is supposed to be $(1-e^{-1})\cdot p?$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Sorry,sir.I will edit it

Comment: This still has nothing t9 d9 with the upper and lower bound if the limit, which is your title - if the conjecture is true, the limit is infinity. What you might want is an upper and lower bound for $limsup f(p)/p$ and $\liminf f(p)/p.$